# A combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, affine-geometry, chessboard

Let us look on a $p\times p$ board (the $(\mathbb{F}_p)^2$ plane)  with a single piece on the down left corner $(0,0)$. This is a special piece that has $3$ legal moves:

1. Moving one step up $\pmod p$
2. Moving one step to the right $\pmod p$
3. Moving x steps to the right and y steps up $\pmod p$, where  $1\leq x,y \leq p-1$

I am trying to prove that the piece can get to any square on the board (except back to the original $(0,0)$ square) in at most $p-1$ legal moves.
I have a proof when $x=y=1$ and when $x+y=0$. Can you help with the other cases?

Thanks

Comment: As some have commented, are we to assume for the type 3 move that the $x,y$ are chosen to be *fixed* numbers for the problem? Such as e.g. if $p=5$ the type 3 move might be "3 right, 2 up" [mod 5  in each case].

Comment: $p$ is prime. For every couple $x,y\neq 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not always possible. For a counterexample let $p=7$, $(x,y)=(6,2)$ and pick $(u,v)=(5,3)$ as the square you want to reach. Try as you may, you will need at least $8$ moves (for a proof see the argument below).

However, I can prove that this can always be done, if we make the extra assumption that $x+y\not\equiv 1\pmod p$.

---

The various ways of using moves of the 3 types, say $a_i$ moves if type $i$, $i=1,2,3$, amount to studying the set of solutions $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\Bbb{F}_p^3$ of the underdetermined system
$$
a_1(0,1)+a_2(1,0)+a_3(x,y)=(u,v). \qquad(*)
$$
We easily see that $a_3\in\Bbb{F}_p$ can be chosen any which way want, and it determines the solution uniquely. So the solutions of $(*)$ are parametrized by $t\in\Bbb{F}_p$ as
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(v-ty,u-tx,t).\qquad(**)
$$
Let's denote by $|a|$, $a\in\Bbb{F}_p$, the "integer value" of an element $a$, so $|a|$ will be an integer in the range $[0,p-1]$. The number of moves required by the solution $(**)$ 
is thus
$$
S(t)=|v-ty|+|u-tx|+|t|.
$$

An averaging argument follows.
Let's begin by calculating the sum of all these possibilities
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}S(t)=\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}|v-ty|+\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}|u-tx|+\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}|t|.
$$
Because you assumed that neither $x$ nor $y$ is $\equiv 0\pmod p$, all three sums on the r.h.s. have all the numbers $0,1,\ldots,p-1$ as terms in some order. For example, $|v-ty|\equiv v-ty\pmod p$, so pairwise non-congruent choices for $t$ lead to non-congruent, and hence distinct, values of $|v-ty|$.

Therefore we can conclude that
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}S(t)=\frac32p(p-1).
$$
We view this as saying that, with the parameter $t$ varying, the average number of moves that you need in different solutions of $(*)$ is $3(p-1)/2$.

Let's look at the distribution of the move counts $S(t)$. We seee that
$$
S(t)=|v-ty|+|u-tx|+|t|\equiv (u-tx)+(v-ty)+t=u+v-t(x+y-1)\pmod p.
$$
So if we assume that $x+y\not\equiv1\pmod p$, it follows that $S(t)\not\equiv S(t')$ whenever $t\not\equiv t'$. In particular the numbers $S(t), t=0,1,\ldots,p-1$,  are all distinct in this case! We can deduce that at least one of them is $<p$. For otherwise their sum would be at least
$p+(p+1)+\cdots+(2p-1)=p(3p-1)/2>3p(p-1)/2$ contradicting the earlier result about their average.

Unfortunately, when $x+y\equiv1\pmod p$ things can go South. In the earlier example case $p=7$, $(x,y)=(6,2)$, $(u,v)=(5,3)$ we easily see that $S(t)=8$ for all but a single choice of $t$ with the exceptional value being $S(6)=|4|+|5|+|6|=15$. The average is still as predicted, because $(6\cdot8+1\cdot15)/7=9=3(7-1)/2$. Observe that, again in accordance with the earlier calculations, here all the move counts $S(t)$ are congruent to $u+v=8$ modulo $7$.

Comment: Can you prove the $x+y$ not conjugate 1?
Where is the argument below?

Comment: Sorry @Michael. I clicked too soon. I still need to type a bit more... Ok. I'm done typing now.

Comment: I still don't understand why this implies that $x+y\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ is not solvable and in other cases it is?

Comment: @MichaelChapman When $x+y\equiv1\pmod p$ it may or may not be solvable. The claims I make are 1) it is always solvable when $x+y\not\equiv1\pmod p$, and 2) it is not always solvable when $x+y\equiv1\pmod p$.